# Countplot against continuous data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to do a countplot of a binary variable against a continuous one so that it should be binned accordingly. Currently I can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "ind": np.random.random(100) > 0.5,
        "value": np.random.random(100),
    })
    .assign(cut=lambda df: pd.cut(df.value, bins=10, labels=False))
    .groupby("cut")
    .agg({"ind": sum})
    .plot.bar()
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

but I am not satisfied with the implementation because:

- it requires to create a variable just for plotting
- it places wrong ticks and labels in the graph

I would like to plot the actual data and have a x axis with the true relevant information.

Comment: Remove `labels=False` and you would have the x axis with *True relevant information*

Comment: and is there any plotting ops that could do the cut+groupby itself?

Comment: Is `ind` always `True/False` (or `1/0`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ind` is Boolean and you want to count the `True` values as suggested in the question title, you can use `hist`:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "ind": np.random.random(100) > 0.5,
        "value": np.random.random(100),
    })
    .query('ind>0')
    .hist('value', bins=10, edgecolor='w', grid=False)
    
)
```

Output:

[image]